Is the Chu-Liu/Edmond algorithm greedy in some cases?
I was learning about arborescences in graphs and came across the Chu-Liu/Edmond algorithm for finding the minimum-weight arborescence in a given directed graph.
The authors start with the premise that a greedy, Prim-like method wouldn't work in this case, and go on to explain the algorithm like this:

The first step is to create a new graph $G′$ by subtracting some
weight from each outgoing arc from a vertex, such that there is at
least one arc of weight 0. That is, set $$w(a′) ← w(a) − M_G(v)$$ for all $a ∈ ∂^+v$ and each $v ∈ V$. where $∂^+v$ is the set of edges going out of $v$.
 Now each vertex has at least one 0-weight arc leaving it. Now, for
each vertex, pick an arbitrary 0-weight arc out of it. If this choice is an arborescence, this must be the minimum-weight arborescence, since all arc weights are still nonnegative. Otherwise, the graph consist of some connected components... < material related to cycle contraction >

Let us stop right here. My question is, what does the first step even contribute? Is this simply not a greedy solution (for the part where the selection of $0$-weight edges/arcs creates an arborescence) where for each vertex $v$ we simply select any one of the minimum-weight outgoing edges from $v$?
Or is there some significance that I miss?

...presumably it contributes the prerequisites for performing the rest of the algorithm? It's not clear what you're asking.

I am asking what is the point of stating that a greedy algorithm does not work in the case of directed graphs when clearly the Chu-Liu algorithm seems to be a greedy one

There is, first of all, an important distinction between

Greedily picking an arborescence by a Prim-like method that selects the best viable edge over and over.
Greedily picking the best edge out of every vertex, and stopping if the result happens to be an arborescence.

The first of these is definitely a greedy algorithm, and it makes sense to say that it does not work: it executes a heuristic that is not necessarily globally optimal. The second of these could be thought of as a greedy algorithm - there is not a formal definition of what makes an algorithm greedy - but to my mind, there is an important distinction.
It does not make sense to say that the second algorithm does not work: there is absolutely no question that picking the best edge out of every vertex produces a set of edges out of every vertex with the lowest possible sum. It is not a heuristic for that, but the clearly optimal solution... to a much easier problem. The only issue is that it might not be an arborescence - but if it is, then great!

Then, of course, there's the further consideration that this is only the first step of an overall algorithm. The overall algorithm is certainly not greedy - because, after all, what's about to happen in the likely case that the chosen arcs are not an arborescence is that we go back and edit this choice of arcs somehow. One defining feature of a greedy algorithm is that we never go back and edit our choices!

Ah, the last line definitely cleared it up for me! By any chance would you recommend some good resources on this algorithm?

I don't know, I just read about it on Wikipedia a bit.
